# Could setting an independent variable early, increase performance?

Tags: cuda

> Threads don’t stall on memory access

From the famous paper http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf by Vasily Volkov

I am assuming based on this statement that this:

```
__device__ int a;
int b, c, d;
a = b * c;
// Do some work that is independent of 'a'
// ...
d = a + 1;
```

Is faster than this

```
__device__ int a;
int b, c, d;
a = b * c;
d = a + 1;
// Do some work that is independent of 'a'
// ...
```

I am only assuming that because I am giving the chance to the thread to execute different instructions while writing to the global memory, while in the second approach I am not.

**Is my assumption right?**

And if my assumption is right, then is it a good practice to set all variables that are going to be used later, in the beginning of the kernel? Given that they are independent from each other, also assuming that `a` is not cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really the stall referenced is a memory *read*.

It is pointing out that a memory read does not generate a stall, *using the value that is read* assuming it's not available, causes the stall.

Suppose I have:

```
__device__ int a[32];
```

Then this thread code does not cause a stall (although it generates a memory transaction):

```
int b = a[0];
```

But if I do this, I will get a stall:

```
int b = a[0];
int c = a[1];
int d = b * c; // stall occurs here
```

Therefore, if I can do this:

```
int b = a[0];
int c = a[1];

//  do lots of other work here
int d = b * c; // this might not stall
```

For Fermi and Kepler GPUs, *writes* (and reads from values previously written, assuming they have not been evicted from the cache) to global memory are serviced by caches, so thread code that appears to be writing to global memory is usually writing to the L1 or L2 cache, and the actual write transaction to global memory will occur later, and does not necessarily cause a stall of any kind.

So in your example, ordinarily `a` will be serviced by a cache:

```
__device__ int a;
int b, c, d;
a = b * c; // a gets written to cache
d = a + 1; // a is serviced from cache
```

Note that servicing from the cache is still slower than the fastest access mechanisms (e.g. registers and shared mem) but it's much much faster than a global memory stall.

Having said all this, the compiler will ordinarily do a number of things that may affect this.  First of all, rather than you manually re-ordering your code, the compiler may spot independent work, and, to some degree, re-order your code for you.  Secondly, in your example, the compiler will spot that `a` is re-used and most likely assign it to a register variable, in addition to updating the value in global memory at some point.  The fact that it is in a register means using `a` in the last line of your example above will most likely get serviced out of the register, not global memory or the cache.

So to answer your questions, I would say that generally, your assumption will not be correct.  The compiler will spot the re-use of `a` and assign it to a register, completely eliminating the hazard that you think exists.  In theory, if there were no caches (true for compute 1.x devices) and no registers, then the compiler might be forced to use global memory as you suggest, but in practice it won't happen.

Comment: The CUDA compiler schedules instructions according to data dependencies. It's aware of long-latency instructions like loads, and tries to schedule them early. Generally there is no need to re-arrange source code to account for long latency operations but the compiler may not be able to move loads across branches or function calls. There is a trade-off with register usage. The further ahead the compiler schedules loads the longer the live ranges of temp regs and the higher the register pressure. Striking a good balance is particularly difficult on Fermi-class GPUs due to the small register file